# NetCore 3.1 ApiController routes 404 on IIS server but not while debugging locally

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, iis-10, .net-core-3.1

I have a very simple app that has both MVC and API Controllers in it. Both work locally using VS 2019 and the IIS Debugger. However, when I deploy this project to a Windows Server 2016 w/ IIS 10, the API Controller Routes all 404. The MVC Routes work w/o issue.

Here is my code for the API Controller

```
[ApiController]
public class LeadController : ControllerBase
{
  [Route( "api/lead/submit" )]
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Post( )
  {
     IFormCollection form = await HttpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
     IFormFileCollection files = form?.Files;

     var form_fields = form.Select( f => new KeyValuePair<String, String>( f.Key, f.Value ) );
     return ( new { recieved_payload = form_fields } );
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main( string[] args )
   {
      CreateHostBuilder( args ).Build().Run();
   }

   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder( string[] args ) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults( webBuilder =>
            {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            } );
 }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
   {
      public Startup( IConfiguration configuration )
      {
         Configuration = configuration;
      }

      public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
      {
         services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
      }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
      public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env )
      {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

         app.UseStaticFiles();

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseAuthorization();

         app.UseEndpoints( endpoints =>
          {
             endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" );
          } );
      }
   }
```

I have tried publishing the project as self-contained and framework-dependent, x86, x64, and portable. None of which make any difference.

I have also made changes to the AppPool settings: .Net 4.0 to No Managed Code. This also does not change the behavior of the application.

It appears to only be problematic for Controllers using [ApiController] - returning json and HttpPost works fine in normal MVC Controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Test()
{
   return Json( new { worked = true } );
}
```

Working localhost request:
[image]

404ing production request:
[image]

Edit: Added web.config and IIS config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Etna.Api.Luxury.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you could check your web.config or applicationhost.config to make sure there is no url rewrite rule enabled in your application. Besides, I suggest you could post the IIS folder directory to us to check what has happened.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I added web.config code and also the IIS  AppPool settings. IIS directory  has the typical publish files.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use IIS [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to check if the request has sent to the asp.net core module.